# el nombre global count no está definido, pero es una funcion

Tags: python, python-2.x

Intenté crear mi propio Counter con un emulador sobre mi telefono:

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array=array
        self.count=count()
    def count(self):
        c = []
        for y in set(self.array):
            count = 0
            for x in self.array:
                if x==y:
                    self.count+=1                    
                    c.append({y:self.count})
                    return c
```

Sin embargo cuando llamo el metodo count() me dice que el nombre global `count` no está definido:

```
Python 2.5.6 (r256:88840, Jan 22 2013, 15:38:34)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin.
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "%magic" for more information.

>>> from Count import Counter
>>> c = Counter(inputs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<PythonForiOS-Input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Counter' is not defined

>>> inputs = ["truc", "truc", "machin", "bidule","bidule"]
>>> c = Counter(inputs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<PythonForiOS-Input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Counter' is not defined

>>> from Count import Counter
>>> c = Counter(inputs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<PythonForiOS-Input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/var/mobile/Applications/711B4F4A-BDE2-4988-9642-41D9CFD5E5FB/Documents/User Scripts/Count.py", line 4, in __init__
    self.count=count()
NameError: global name 'count' is not defined
```

## Actualizacion

Actualizé el código con tu consejo. He movido un poco el `return c`, pero me temo que no puedo conseguir el contador.

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array=array
        self.var_count=self.count()
    def count(self):
        c = []
        for y in set(self.array):
            var = 0
            for x in self.array:
                if x==y:
                    var+=1                    
             c.append({y:var})
        return c
```

En efecto me devuelve:

```
>>> inputs = ["truc", "truc", "machin", "bidule","bidule"]
>>> from Count import Counter
>>> c = Counter(inputs)
>>> c.var_count
[{'machin': 1}, {'bidule': 1}, {'bidule': 2}, {'truc': 1}, {'truc': 2}]
```

Comment: La línea `self.count=count()` no tiene mucho sentido, a menos que tengas una función afuera de la clase que se llame `count()`. Si quieres ejecutar automáticamente el método `count()`, entonces debes reemplazar esa linea por algo como `self.tu_variable = self.count()`

Answer (score 0):

Puedo observar dos problemas en tu código.

El primero es: estas definiendo en el constrtuctor que el objeto de la clase `self.count` será igual a `count()` que basicamente es el mismo `self.count`, por lo que te recomiendo cambiar cualquiera de los dos nombres, el de tu variable `count` o el de tu función `count()`, ya que para ambos casos usas `self` y vas a reemplazarlo.

El segundo es que para acceder a la funcion desde su propia clase debes usar self.defname, tu código quedaría así:

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array=array
        self.var_count=self.count()
    def count(self):
        c = []
        for y in set(self.array):
            count = 0
            for x in self.array:
                if x==y:
                    self.count+=1                    
                    c.append({y:self.count})
                    return c
```

Espero te sea útil.

Answer (score 0):

No sólo fue necesario cambiar el nombre de las variables para evitar tener una variable con el mismo nombre que una función (por alguna razón que desconozco), sino también desplazar `c.append` y `return c`:

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array=array
        self.var_count=self.count()
    def count(self):
        c = []
        for y in set(self.array):
            var = 0
            for x in self.array:
                if x==y:
                    var+=1                    
             c.append({y:var})
        return c
```